# How to know the list of jars used by application

Tags: java, tomcat, maven, jar

I loaded my project into eclipse and deployed on tomcat. In eclipse there are red cross marks appearing which indicate that there are errors. But my application is getting executed by maven and running good. So to eliminate the red marks I need to add external jars to the build path in eclipse. If yes, how do I know which jars are used by my application?
Where can I get them?

Comment: what kind of web app are you building?

Comment: @codeMan Why does it matter?

Comment: How did you load your project into eclipse ? Did you try 'maven eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse' ?

Comment: I didn't use maven eclipse:... to load the project.. just clicked the new project and selected dynamic web project and linked the src folder

Answer (score 1):

Why wouldn't you just use a Maven plugin (e.g., m2eclipse) and let it resolve the dependencies?

In any case, there are several ways to get the list of jars used by a Maven project, e.g.:

```
mvn dependency:list
```

Comment: in my code there are many under lines in red colour saying "xxx cannot be resolved to a .." what would be the problem?

Comment: @user1949737 You don't have the required libraries on Eclipse's build path.

Comment: i've added all the libraries to the build path.. even now the same red marks are appearing...

Comment: i've added all the jar files that are present in lib folder of the project in webapps. Are those enough? or something more has to be added?

Comment: @ram I don't know what was in the lib folder of the project in webapps, so I have no idea.